# Autocomplete CakePHP not displaying

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I'm trying to get auto complete to display my invoice ids when they're being typed but I don't believe the script is running on my ctp file. I'm trying to follow this guide http://www.naidim.org/cakephp-3-tutorial-18-autocomplete I'm not quite sure if it is actually accessing the funtion. I've tried to look at many guides and tutorials but can't seem to get any working on cakephp 3.

My test.ctp

```
    <?php use Cake\Routing\Router; ?>
<?php
echo $this->Html->script('//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js');
echo $this->Html->script('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js');
echo $this->Html->css('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
?>

<script>
    jQuery('#id').autocomplete({
        source:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Invoices', 'action' => 'getAll')); ?>',
        minLength: 1
    });

</script>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id', ['type' => 'int']);
    ?>
```

my getAll funtion

```
public function getAll()
{
    if ($this->requrest->is('ajax')) {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $name = $this->request->query['term'];
        $items = $this->Invoices->find('all', [
        'conditions' => [
        'id LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->query('term') . '%'
        ]
    ]);
        $resultsArr = [];
        foreach ($results as $result) {
             $resultsArr[] =['label' => $result['id'], 'value' => $result['id']];
        }
        echo json_encode($resultsArr);
    }
}
```

my invoice table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I believe that it's not even triggered at all because nothing happens in the console when you enter an id also if you change the routing path to an invalid path in the test.ctp no errors occur. You could test it here team.southpacificavionics.com/invoices/test by signing in with the username "guest" and password "password"

Comment: What error are you getting? When (if?) it hits the autocomplete method, what is it passing? Where is the code stopping?  Is it getting triggered at all? You need to do some initial debugging then post those results here to narrow it down.  Otherwise it's just asking "hey, why isn't this working?", which won't get good responses.

Comment: I believe that it's not even triggered at all because nothing happens in the console when you enter an id also if you change the routing path to an invalid path in the test.ctp no errors occur. You could test it here http://team.southpacificavionics.com/invoices/test by signing in with the username "guest" and password "password". Also thanks for the tips I am new here :).